# how do i total up every row laravel

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, count

i want to know how can i call the total in that column 'status'

in that column i have either= "Match", "No Answer", "Missing Intent", "Webhook Fail", "Low Confidence" depending on another function

to count for example only "match" is possible

but now i want to total up "Match" + "No Answer" + "Missing Intent" + "Webhook Fail" + "Low Confidence"

how can i do that? i tried the below way but its not working

```html
foreach($sessionID as $key => $value)
{
  $countMatch = count(DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $key)->where('status', 'Match')->get());
  $countNoAnswer = count(DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $key)->where('status', 'No Answer')->get());
  $countMissingIntent = count(DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $key)->where('status', 'Missing Intent')->get());
  $countWebhookFail = count(DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $key)->where('status', 'Webhook Fail')->get());
  $countLowConfidence = count(DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $key)->where('status', 'Low Confidence')->get());
  $totalQuestion = $countMatch + $countNoAnswer + $countMissingIntent + $countWebhookFail + $countLowConfidence;
  $data[$key] = [
                  'total' => $totalQuestion,
                  'match' => $countMatch,
                  'no answer' => $countNoAnswer,
                  'missing intent' => $countMissingIntent,
                  'webhook fail' => $countWebhookFail,
                  'low confidence' => $countLowConfidence,
                ];
}
```

```html
$totalQuestion = $countMatch + $countNoAnswer + $countMissingIntent + $countWebhookFail + $countLowConfidence;
```

Comment: You could use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY status`, or you could use `SUM` AND `IF`. It depends whether you'd rather have one row with a column for each status type, or a row for each status type.